Why does my Labists X1 mini printer float 1 cm above the bed even after homing it?
I pulled my Labists X1 mini printer out of jail after about 3 years, and tried to get it working. I'd only ever printed the pre-sliced files from the supplier, but now needed something I'd designed myself.
It wasn't feeding the PLA which I tracked down to some having snapped off in the head and crumbled enough during its hibernation to ignore the feed wheel and wedge against the lower guide tube - a bit daunting to have to get in there, but I managed and was pleased to have broken the ice that it's pretty simple in there mechanically.
I tried to tram the table, since I'd removed and reinserted the head, but pressing 'home' left the head floating about 10 mm above the bed. I opened it back up to see if I'd inserted the head badly, but it looked like the YouTube video I was referring to. Now it wouldn't go down from 90 mm.
I installed pronterface and plugged the usb in (first time ever) but using the direct drive buttons - x and y were fine, but z stubbornly refused to drop lower then 9 cm above the table (where I'd had it for repairing the head). I tried unplugging the power and USB, and now it would drop to 1 cm again, but still wouldn't touch the bed.
I tried G114 to find where it thought it was, and it reported z to be zero. I tried using the code 'home' command in case the button was doing something fancy, but it still floated. I tried the factory reset code, no joy. I tried sending z to -10, nada.

The control cable was tucked in over the z end of travel microswitch. I think when the head refused to drop below 9 cm the control box's cable must have been resting on the switch instead, and I had to move the control box to power-cycle it - my bedroom table is a bit cluttered!
Once my new non-crumbly PLA arrives, I'll be printing some sort of guard for that switch! :D

Welcome and thanks for sharing your experience, I have had this happen in the past myself!
